# Why does Excel use 3 decimal places for currency when I have the cell set to 2 decimal places

Tags: microsoft-excel

For my example, I have a base price of $23. The Standard price is 20% increase of that. Late price is 20% increase from standard pricing.

My problem is I am getting 3 decimal places for some of the prices.

In Cell E2, my price is correct at $34.78 but I have another cell to get this data and add text but this cell is 3 decimal places, so it reads $34.776. I need this cell to only show 2 decimal places.

[image: excel table]

Link to file: https://sourceoneevents-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/p/andrew/EQso6uh74xBKjwzRFmFQqaEBaCuvI8AHrBCBZn1jhz2Few?e=N19BJ6

Comment: Use `TEXT()` function since you are concatenating the price returned from cell `E2` with "per sq ft" it shows the actual value of the cell

Comment: Excel always uses more digits (up to 15), unless you use `ROUND()` (or other means to get the same / similar result). And as shown in the answer below, text mode formatted numbers need to be created with `TEXT()` where the second argument is the same as used in the "Format Cell" (CTRL+1) dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `TEXT()` function here.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A2</kbd>

```
=TEXT(E2,"$ #,##0.00")& " per sq. ft."
```

---

Comment: Thank you! I will mark the answer correct when I can.

Comment: @AndrewH thanks sounds good, glad to know it worked!